# How to submit bootsrap datepicker with SpringMVC AngularJs in Mysql

Tags: angularjs, rest, spring-mvc, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using Angular Twitter Bootstrap Spring MVC, Data and Security for my Web apps,here i have some problem i don't know how to submit a form with bootsrap datepicker ,the insertion value of the fiel date is null,i really don't know how to use Datepicker with Spring MVC , when i submit the form the value isn't mapp into database mysql via hibernate

My JSP code is like bellow :

```
<link href="<c:url  value='/resources/date-css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css'/>" rel="stylesheet"/>  
        <script src="<c:url value='/resources/date-css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js' />"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value='/resources/date-css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.fr.js' />"></script> 

<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Date </label>
    <div class="controls input-append date form_date" 
         data-date="" 
         data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" 
         data-link-field="dtp_input2" 
         data-link-format="yyyy-mm-dd">

        <input  type="text" 
                required 
                ng-datepicker 
                ng-options="datepickerOptions"
                placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"  />

        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-remove"></i></span>
        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
    </div>
    <input  type="hidden" value="{{ctrs.dateDebut}}"
            ng-model="ctrs.dateDebut"
            name="dateDebut"  
            id="dtp_input2" 
            class="ng-invalid-required"/> 

</div>
-----------
```

script javascript is like beloow :

```
$(function(){
    $('.form_date').datetimepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        language: 'fr',
        weekStart: 1,
        todayBtn:  1,
        autoclose: 1,
        todayHighlight: 1,
        startView: 2,
        minView: 2,
        forceParse: 0

    });
    $('.form_date input[type=text]').change(function() {
        //$('.ng-pristine').val($(this).val());
        $('.ng-invalid-required').val($(this).val());
    });
});

</script>
```

i'm using Angularjs to put data and get the returned data from the server, in my controllerAngular i have this function in my Angular controllers that allow me to pass data to the backend

```
$scope.createContact = function (newContactForm) {
        if (!newContactForm.$valid) {
            console.debug(newContactForm);
            console.log('ici');
            $scope.displayValidationError = true;
            return;
        }
        $scope.lastAction = 'create';
        var url = $scope.url;
        var config = {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}};
        $scope.addSearchParametersIfNeeded(config, false);
        $scope.startDialogAjaxRequest();
        $http.post(url, $.param($scope.ctrs), config)
            .success(function (data) {
                console.log('ici1');
                $scope.finishAjaxCallOnSuccess(data, "#addContactsModal", false);
                console.log('ici2');
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log('ero1');
                $scope.handleErrorInDialogs(status);
                console.log("error");
            });
    };
```

Spring controller is like bellow :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<?> create(@ModelAttribute("ctrs") Contrat ctrs,
                                @RequestParam(required = false) String searchFor,
                                @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = DEFAULT_PAGE_DISPLAYED_TO_USER) int page,
                                Locale locale) {
    contraatsService.save(ctrs);

}
```

Please help me!

Comment: Try using angular ui datepicker - Bootstrap Datepicker configured for angular js. https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker

Comment: I'm using [bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker](https://github.com/Gillardo/bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker) and it's pretty easy to understand, it's configured for AngularJS itself. I played a bit with its [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/S8UqwvXNGmDcPXV7a0N3) before using it. Hope It's going to be helpfull.

Comment: Hi thanks for your replay , in my webapp i'm using 
 AngularJS v1.0.5 and i was tring this one http://plnkr.co/edit/gM5DvVSSy5mWULUPp8nN?p=preview and when i add angular.js  AngularJS v1.3.0-rc.3  i got this error Invalid isolate scope definition for directive datepickerPopup: =?